# How to replace " \\u0027 " by " ' " in python?

Tags: python, string, unicode, escaping, encode

i am new to python, and im trying to program a scraper.

firstly, i extract this kind of string in a variable (lets call it ***data[1]***, because it's contained in an array):

> \"description\":\"Alors qu\\u0027ils montaient dans l\\u0027un des
>   couloirs du versant nord du Hohneck (\\"le premier couloir \u00E0
>   droite\\"), deux alpinistes ont d\u00E9clench\u00E9 une plaque et ont
>   \u00E9t\u00E9 emport\u00E9s tous les deux. L\\u0027un sera enseveli et
>   l\\u0027autre ne pourra d\u00E9clencher l\\u0027alerte qu\\u0027\u00E0
>   la nuit. La victime ne sera retrouv\u00E9e que d\u00E9but avril.
>   \u003cbr\u003e Sur la photo prise en f\u00E9vrier 2011, le
>   trac\u00E9 approximatif de l\\u0027avalanche a \u00E9t\u00E9
>   repr\u00E9sent\u00E9.\",

then, i use :

`data = data[1].encode().decode('unicode-escape')`

but it gives me :

> "description":"Alors qu\u0027ils montaient dans l\u0027un des couloirs
>   du versant nord du Hohneck (\"le premier couloir à droite\"), deux
>   alpinistes ont déclenché une plaque et ont été emportés tous les deux.
>   L\u0027un sera enseveli et l\u0027autre ne pourra déclencher
>   l\u0027alerte qu\u0027à la nuit. La victime ne sera retrouvée que
>   début avril. \u003cbr\u003e Sur la photo prise en février 2011, le
>   tracé approximatif de l\u0027avalanche a été représenté.",

indeed, char with accent had been replaced but apostrophes stay unprocessed !
It seems the two backslashes are the cause.

i tried several methods :
like decode twice and then "\u0027" become "'", but "é" become "Ã©".

`data.replace('Ã©', 'é')` or `data.replace(u'\u0027', u'é')` dont work

So, do you have any idea how i could fix this probleme ?

Comment: I think the encoding are differents can you do `.encode('unicode-escape').decode('unicode-escape')` or just let the default encoding for encode/decode and see if it works?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to process JSON manually. You should parse JSON with a JSON parser, such as the built-in `json` module.

Comment: Looking at the website from your previous question, it looks like you have a Javascript string literal containing JSON, so you need to parse the Javascript string literal for the JSON string it represents, and then parse the JSON with a JSON parser.

Comment: @yayg,
Both propositions (encode and decode with 'unicode-escape' or empty) lead to the same results, no changes between the in and output string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed !

As user2357112 supports Monica said, i tried to process manually a json.
But doing :

```
data = html_page.find_all("script")
data = re.findall("(?<=JSON\.parse\(')[A-Za-z0-9'.?!/+=;:,()\\\ \"\-{_àâçéèêëíìîôùûæœÁÀÂÃÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÔÙÛ©´<>]*", str(data))

data = data[0].encode().decode('unicode-escape') + "\"\"}"    
data_dict = json.loads(data)
string_data_dict = json.dumps(data_dict)

for cle, val in data_dict.items() :
    print(cle + " : " + str(val))
```

solves the bug.

With this code, an input string like :

```
<script>
var admin = false;
var avalanche = JSON.parse('{...\"description\":\"Alors qu\\u0027ils montaient dans l\\u0027un des couloirs du versant nord du Hohneck (\\\"le premier couloir \u00E0 droite\\\"), deux alpinistes ont d\u00E9clench\u00E9 une plaque et ont \u00E9t\u00E9 emport\u00E9s tous les deux. L\\u0027un sera enseveli et l\\u0027autre ne pourra d\u00E9clencher l\\u0027alerte qu\\u0027\u00E0 la nuit. La victime ne sera retrouv\u00E9e que d\u00E9but avril. \\u003cbr\\u003e Sur la photo prise en f\u00E9vrier 2011, le trac\u00E9 approximatif de l\\u0027avalanche a \u00E9t\u00E9 repr\u00E9sent\u00E9.\",...
```

gives an output like :

```
...
description : Alors qu'ils montaient dans l'un des couloirs du versant nord du Hohneck ("le premier couloir à droite"), deux alpinistes ont déclenché une plaque et ont été emportés tous les deux. L'un sera enseveli et l'autre ne pourra déclencher l'alerte qu'à la nuit. La victime ne sera retrouvée que début avril. <br> Sur la photo prise en février 2011, le tracé approximatif de l'avalanche a été représenté.
...
```

Thanks you.